# How to use KNNImputer in parallel?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Can we use `KNNImputer` in parallel ? (i.e `n_jobs=-1` like other `sklearn` modules) ?

I have a `dataframe` with 20 rows (features) and some of them contains `nan`.

Instead of using `KNNImputer` in sequential way (compute the value of each `nan` in row),
 can we do it in parallel ? (like `n_jobs = -1`) ?

my code for the sequential way looks:

```
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5, weights="uniform", copy=False)
X_new = imputer.fit_transform(X, y)
```

How can we change it to impute in parallel ?

Answer (score 1):

you couldn't use multiprocessing with KNNImputer
and you can check this thread
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18186